# creating figures for table & graphs linkable

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have been trying to make a results page that meets American Chemical Society standards for my chemistry class. I have tried different methods but they aren't exactly what I am looking for. Does anyone know a good general way to make figure citations that can be linked from the text?

Here is a sample results page I made.

````
---
title: "Lab 2 Results"
output: html_document
---


```{r, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpmisc)

solution_1 <- tibble(
  aliquot = c(1:7),
  time_sec = c(29.07, 26.72, 25.91, 21.37, 18.98, 18.68, 18.07),
  Cum_time = cumsum(time_sec),
  total_mol_S2O8 = seq(0.0002, length.out = 7, by = 0.0002)
)

solution_2 <- tibble(
  aliquot = c(1:7),
  time_sec = c(29.94, 29.81, 25.71, 24.11, 23.20, 21.69, 21.53),
  Cum_time = cumsum(time_sec),
  total_mol_S2O8 = seq(0.0002, length.out = 7, by = 0.0002)
)

solution_3 <- tibble(
  aliquot = c(1:7),
  time_sec = c(26.81, 21.49, 19.70, 18.98, 19.26, 18.85, 21.73),
  Cum_time = cumsum(time_sec),
  total_mol_S2O8 = seq(0.0002, length.out = 7, by = 0.0002)
)

colnames(solution_1) <- c('aliquot', 'time', 'cum_time', 'moles_S2O8')
colnames(solution_2) <- c('aliquot', 'time', 'cum_time', 'moles_S2O8')
colnames(solution_3) <- c('aliquot', 'time', 'cum_time', 'moles_S2O8')

```


```{r, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE}
knitr::kable(solution_1, caption = 'figure 1.1: Solution 1',col.names = c('aliquot', 'time(s)', 'cumulative time (s)', 'total moles of S2O8 consumed'))

```

```{r, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, fig.cap = 'figure 1.2: graph of rate of color change in solution after adition of S2O8'}

ggplot(data = solution_1, mapping = aes(x = time, y = moles_S2O8)) +
  stat_poly_line(se = FALSE)+
  stat_poly_eq(use_label('eq'), 
               label.x = 'right') +
  geom_point()+
    labs(y = bquote('moles of'~S[2]*O[8]^-4),
         x = 'time(s)',
         title = bquote('Rate of reaction per aliquot of'~S[2]*O[8]^-4),
           subtitle = 'Solution 1')

```

```{r, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE}
knitr::kable(solution_2, caption = 'figure 2: Solution 2',col.names = c('aliquot', 'time(s)', 'cumulative time (s)', 'total moles of S2O8 consumed'))
```

```{r, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE}
ggplot(data = solution_2, mapping = aes(x = time, y = moles_S2O8)) +
  stat_poly_line(se = FALSE)+
  stat_poly_eq(use_label('eq'), 
               label.x = 'right') +
  geom_point()+
  labs(y = bquote('moles of'~S[2]*O[8]^-4),
       x = 'time(s)',
       title = bquote('Rate of reaction per aliquot of'~S[2]*O[8]^-4),
       subtitle = 'Solution 2')
```

```{r, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE}
knitr::kable(solution_3, caption = 'figure 3: Solution 3',col.names = c('aliquot', 'time(s)', 'cumulative time (s)', 'total moles of S2O8 consumed'))
```

```{r, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE}
ggplot(data = solution_3, mapping = aes(x = time, y = moles_S2O8)) +
  stat_poly_line(se = FALSE)+
  stat_poly_eq(use_label('eq'), 
               label.x = 'right') +
  geom_point()+
  labs(y = bquote('moles of'~S[2]*O[8]^-4),
       x = 'time(s)',
       title = bquote('Rate of reaction per aliquot of'~S[2]*O[8]^-4),
       subtitle = 'Solution 3')
```

```{css, echo = FALSE}
table {
  margin: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}
table thead th { border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; }
th, td { padding: 5px; }
thead, tfoot, tr:nth-child(even) { background: #eee; }

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```
````

Comment: What are you using ``Rmarkdown` ? What are the different methods you have tried? And try to condense the whole code to one example (that you then can then transfer for your needs)!

Comment: Does it have to be rmd? For a general way for tables and figures with bit more convenient cross referencing, perhaps consider Quarto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the following code in a Rmarkdown document for PDF output :

'''
{r fig, fig.cap = "\label{fig:myfig}Plot"}

plot(rnorm(10), type = "l")
'''

Here is my figure : \ref{fig:myfig}.

For HTML output, you can consider knitting to bookdown::html_document2 :

```
output:
 bookdown::html_document2
link-citations: yes
```

with the option link-citations: yes. After in the text, you can use \@ref(fig:myfig)